# EF Core IgnoreQueryFilters behavior on multiple subsequent queries

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i've a problem with the IgnoreQueryFilters.

I've implemented soft-delete using the HasQueryFilter ( in the OnModelCreating i apply the global query filter to every entity which implements a particular interface ).

The problem is that if i launch a query 2 times in the same request:

- the first time asking for also the "IsDeleted = true"  entities ( so including IgnoreQueryFilters ),
- and the second time asking only for the "IsDeleted = false" ( so not including the IgnoreQueryFilters)

the second time i still get also the "deleted" entities.

I think that this happens because when i launch the query for the second time, the entities are already in the context and i get them instead of the right results.

Here how i build the method for "including / excluding" the deleted entities.

```
// this is my repo pattern implementation
    public class MyEntityRepo()
    {
    ....
      public Task<List<MyEntity>> GetEntityByUserId(int userId, bool ignoreQueryFilter = false)
      {
           var query = context.blabla
                    .Include(c => c.blabla2)
                    .Where(c => c.ApplicationUserId == userId);
    
                if (ignoreQueryFilter)
                {
                    query = query.IgnoreQueryFilters();
                    
                }
    
                var result = await query.ToListAsync();
    
                return result;
      }
    
    }
```

Now if in a service i call it this way:

```
public void MyServiceMethod()
{
    ...
    var IncludeDeleted = await myEntityRepo.GetEntityByUserId(1, true);
    
    //Here i need to do a sync with other data and for this reason i need also the deleted entities
    foreach( var e in includeDeleted)
    {
        // do something
    }
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    
    //Now that my data is correctly synced i've to get the data again but this time excluding the deleted entities
    // and it fails
    
    var ExcludeDeleted = await myEntityRepo.GetEntityByUserId(1, false);
    
    return ExcludeDeleted;
}
```

The only way i found to solve the problem is to do something like context.ChangeTracker.Clear() before the second call to myEntityRepo.GetEntityByUserId, but is this the right way to go?

Since in real the method is a little bit more complex and can be re-used in other areas, i'm not sure that calling a Clear is a good idea because tomorrow it might be called in a bigger method and cause unexpected problems.

What's the best practice to use when i need to get data with and without query filter?
Is it ok to clear the change  tracker?
If yes, what's the best time to clear it? in the GetEntityByUserId if i just ignoredTheFilters ( for consistency ) or after, in the caller method, whenever i find a problem like this one?

Actually i've also thinked about removing the GlobalQueryFilter usage and replace it with methods in the repos that get or exclude deleted entities... yes i've to remember to always filter out but feels more practical.

Comment: You can clear ChangeTracker safely after any `SaveChanges`, but for sure, if you do not store references to previously loaded records.

Comment: Hi Danyliv, thanks for your answer! But do you think that this is the way to go or this is a "workaround"?

Comment: IMHO, it is normal behaviour. Reset `DbContext` state. It is how DbContextFactory works.